# How can i make full post-back request from angularJS to phalcon php

Tags: php, ajax, angularjs, postback, phalcon

I have an angularJS + PHP application. What i would like to achieve is a "Full Post" request to Phalcon PHP controller.

**Angular:**

```
$http.post('/controller/sampleAction/', {params}).
   success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

   }).
   error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

   });
```

**Phalcon PHP:**

```
public function sampleAction()
{
    ControllerBase::indexAction();

    if ($this->request->isPost() == true) {
        // Access POST data
        $this->view->paramA = $this->request->getPost("paramA");
        $this->view->paramB= $this->request->getPost("paramB");
    }
}
```

I am getting to phalcon controller, setting my view params but the view is not rendered because its an AJAX request. How can i still use POST function and redirect/render the sampleAction view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are my findings and solution for my problem:

1. Apparently Phalcon **does** return the view.
2. The reason that the view was not rendered as a full post-back response is that Angular is a **Single-Page** JS framework, so if i want to use it i should build my app accordingly.
3. So, instead of requesting a full page from Phalcon i changed my architecture, so i will only get relevant Json data from Phalcon while rendering the view purely in angularJS using a directive.

Answer (score 2):

> but the view is not rendered because its an AJAX request

False. Unsless you have disabled view by yourself in case of ajax request. Check out your code, share us whats happening in `ControllerBase::indexAction()` and in `initialize()` if defined and something related to requests/view.

Comment: you are right regarding about rendering the view. while i was monitoring the network i see in the response the relevant view, but nothing is changed on the screen. how can i make the page to reload that data, which probably need to be compiled with angular afterwards?